# Fiddler gateway proxy username/password

Tags: proxy, fiddler

I'm trying to intercept a web application which uses a HTTP proxy (basic HTTP auth password protected) to access its resources.

In Fiddler options, there is a setting for manual proxy configuration. But in that field, I can only define the proxy address and port. I need to define an username/password combination for upstream proxy.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If the site is using basic auth, you should be able to see the header in fiddler once you start capturing traffic. A proxy would be for all HTTP traffic - I don't think thats what you want.

Comment: The application that I want to debug uses a proxy internally. It allows to change own proxy setting, so I want to put Fiddler there(localhost:8888) and set Fiddler gateway proxy to application's correct proxy (which is HTTP auth protected). This way Fiddler goes into "middle" of this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your scenario is a bit unclear. Clients *should* automatically prompt for proxy credentials when a `HTTP/407` is received, although [many don't](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/10/11/web-proxy-configuration-and-ie11-changes.aspx).

If your question is: "How can I add a `Proxy-Authorization` header to all requests that pass through Fiddler?" then it's pretty simple.

Rules > Customize Rules > Scroll to `OnBeforeRequest` and add:

```
if (!oSession.isHTTPS) 
{
  oSession.oRequest["Proxy-Authorization"] = "Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=";
}
```

Where `dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=` is the base64-encoded version of the "username:password" string. You can use Fiddler's Tools > TextWizard to base64-encode a string.

Comment: Uh... if replacing "Basic" with "NTLM" worked it means that your proxy server is *extremely* buggy.

Comment: Yeah it kind of evoked smile of my face that it actually worked :)